# Issue with replacing NULL sqlite3 database column values with other types in Python 3?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.9

I've run into a problem with the sqlite3 module in Python 3, where I can't seem to figure out how to replace `NULL` values from the database with other ones, mainly strings and integers.

This command doesn't do the job, but also raises no exceptions:
`UPDATE table SET animal='cat' WHERE animal=NULL AND id=32`

The database table column "animal" is of type `TEXT` and gets filled with `NULL`s where no other value has been specified.
The column "id" is primary keyed and thus features only unique integer row indices.

If the column "animal" is defined, not `NULL`, the above command works flawlessly.
I can replace existing strings, integers, and floats with it.

What am I overlooking here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NULL` value in SQL is special, and to compare values against it you need to use the `IS` and `IS NOT` operators.  So your query should be this:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET animal = 'cat'
WHERE animal IS NULL AND id = 32;
```

`NULL` by definition means "unknown" in SQL, and so comparing a column directly against it with `=` also produces an unknown result.